# Prepositions + time

Tags: prepositions, difference, prepositional-phrases

I was wondering if these five sentences share a common meaning:

1. People get older with time.
2. People get older over time.
3. People get older in time.
4. People get older across time.
5. People get older through time.

I can't see much difference in them. Except that **across time** in this context sounds unusual and clumsy.

Comment: *People get older in time* is rather funny. "in time" = eventually. People get old in time, but they're getting older every minute.  Across time and through time refer to "over the ages".  That's funny too. No one would expect people two hundred years ago not to age.

Comment: In time, you will see the difference.

Comment: Perhaps you could come up with a matrix clause that doesn't relate to age?

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo This context interests me.

Comment: You're into tautology?

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo No, but from your explanation I'm seeing a difference. So **with time** or **over time** is about estimation?

Comment: I think the best thing to do is to consult ngram looking for these phrases, and then to consult the attestations to see the various ways in which they're being used. They are not always interchangeable. For example, among the meanings of *with time* are "given some time".  *He'll get over his heartbreak, with time* and  **over time** can mean "as years passed ":  *Over time the building was used as a dance hall, a polling place, and a bicycle shop.*  We wouldn't say "*With time* the building was used as a dance hall, a polling place..."

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo i get it. **over time** is somewhat periodical, while **with time** is **over time into the future**. So, in my case **with time*" is the best choice.